# Downloading multiple files at the same time and continue after all files finished downloading

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

We are writing a little tool that downloads files from our web server and analyzes them. It's a lot of files and it takes about 10 minutes to download, and we want to make the download time shorter by allowing the app to download the files in parallel.

Currently we have a loop the goes over the files list to be download and just downloads them and add the file name to a delimited string:

```
foreach (var File in ServerFiles)
{
    string sFileName = File.Uri.LocalPath.ToString();
    // some internal logic and initialization 
    oBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
    sFiles += sFileName.Replace("/" + Container + "/", "") + ",";
}
```

We've changed it to:

```
foreach (var File in ServerFiles)
{
    string sFileName = File.Uri.LocalPath.ToString();
    // some internal logic and initialization 
    Task downloadTask = oBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
    sFiles += sFileName.Replace("/" + Container + "/", "") + ",";
}
```

now my question is what to I do with the Task I get back. If I just call downloadTask.wait() then it will be just as leaving it as before.

I thought about using continueWith - but what should do inside that block? how would it know that all other files finished downloading?

I even thought about storing tasks in a collection and at the end of the foreach loop write another loop that takes all tasks and and calls the wait method on them.

what is the correct way to solve such problem?

Comment: Are you sure downloading them in parallel will be faster? Did you identified the bottleneck? Source disk, network, destination disk? How is parallelism improving the bottleneck?

Comment: If all the files are indeed on the same server, you will also need to increase [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the tasks in a collection and then call
Task.WaitAll(yourArray);
Your code will be blocked until all tasks complete.
Something like this:

```
var tasks=new List<Task>();
foreach (var File in ServerFiles)
{
    string sFileName = File.Uri.LocalPath.ToString();
    // some internal logic and initialization 
    Task downloadTask = oBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
tasks.Add(downloadTask);
    sFiles += sFileName.Replace("/" + Container + "/", "") + ",";
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
//Continue here
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Parallel.Foreach` to downloaded all the files using separate threads.

Unless you really need/want to concat all the downloaded files into one large string, (and write logic to later retrieve individial files), I instead store the strings in a thread safe list (sush as a System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag which allows multiple threads to write to the list).

```
ConcurrentBag<string> downloadedFiles = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

Parallel.ForEach(ServerFiles, file =>
{
    string sFileName = file.Uri.LocalPath.ToString();
    // some internal logic and initialization 
    oBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
    downloadedFiles.Add(sFileName);
});
```